# Extract names of a sentence with regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm very new with the syntax of regex, I already read some about the libary. I'm trying extract names from a simple sentence, but I found myself in trouble, below I show a exemple of what I've done.

```
x = 'Fred used to play with his brother, Billy, both are 10 and their parents Jude and Edde have two more kids.'

import re

re.findall('^[A-Za-z ]+$',x)
```

Anyone can explain me what is wrong and how to proceed?

Comment: Try `re.findall(r'\b[A-Z][A-Za-z]*\b', x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your regex has two problems.

- You want to extract names of sentence. You need to remove `^` start of line and `$` end of line.
- Name starts with uppercase and does not have space. You should remove   in your regex.

You could use following regex.

```
\b[A-Z][A-Za-z]+\b
```

I also tried to test result on python.

```
x = 'Fred used to play with his brother, Billy, both are 10 and their parents Jude and Edde have two more kids.'

import re

result = re.findall('\\b[A-Z][A-Za-z]+\\b',x)
print(result)
```

Result.

```
['Fred', 'Billy', 'Jude', 'Edde']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
re.findall(r'\b[A-Z]\w*', x)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/kzMUHB/1). It matches words starting with uppercase letter and having any amount of letters, digits or underscores.